# Passing hash to p causes syntax error

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Why do I get this?

```
p {a:3}
# => syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
# => p {a:3}
           ^
```

Comment: It's interpreted as a block, p() {a:3}; rather, you want: p({a:3})

Comment: @LeeJarvis, it answers my question perfectly, unlike the wrong upvoted answer and silent question downvoters.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby has a few oddities in its parsing engine. One is that certain things require parentheses around them.

For instance, this should work.

```
p({a:3})
```

Or this

```
hash = { a: 3 } 
p hash
```

As the other answer pointed out. The reason for this is that the interpreter processes as below.

```
# Input
p { a: 3 }

# What the interpreter sees
p do
  a: 3
end
```

The `Kernel#p` doesn't support blocks, so you must use the parentheses.

Comment: Your `# What the interpreter sees` is wrong. There is nothing bad in `p do ; {a:3} ; end`. The interpreter sees `p do ; a:3 ; end`.